# Python: read a csv file, removed outlier then rebuild the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a csv file "trainning_data.csv" contains 7 columns of data but i only read the last one 
the format of csv file is as below:

```
     A        B      C      D      E      F      Last
1    1.5    14.2   21.5    50.1   25.5   14.2   25.2
2    ...    ...    ...     ...    ...    ...    ...  
3    
.
.
.
```

I read the data file using pandas then visulized it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('trainning_data.csv')
saved_column = df['Last']

plt.plot(saved_column, 'o')
plt.show()
```

then i removed the oulier as:

```
Q1 = np.percentile(saved_column, 25)
Q3 = np.percentile(saved_column, 75)

range=[Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1),Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)];

id_max =  np.where(saved_column>range[1])
id_min =  np.where(saved_column<range[0])

position = np.concatenate( (id_max, id_min), axis=1)

saved_column = np.array(saved_column, dtype = 'double')
new_column = np.delete(saved_column, position.T)



len(new_column)
plt.plot(new_column, 'o')
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0,500)
plt.show()
```

after removed all the outlier, i want to rebuild the data set, i tried:

```
fileHeader = ["Last"]
myFile = open('Training_Data_New.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(myFile)

writer.writerow(fileHeader)
writer.writerows(new_column)
```

but it throws me an Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64

another problem is i need to delete all the data related to the position of the outlier that i found as well. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame` by numopy array and write to file by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
pd.DataFrame({'Last':new_column}).to_csv('Training_Data_New.csv', index=False)
```

Pandas solution for remove outliers:

I think you can use [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html) and filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last for write `DataFrame` to file use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last':[1,2,3,5,8,10,45,100], 'A': np.arange(8)})
print (df)
   A  Last
0  0     1
1  1     2
2  2     3
3  3     5
4  4     8
5  5    10
6  6    45
7  7   100

Q1 = df['Last'].quantile(.25)
Q3 = df['Last'].quantile(.75)
q1 = Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
q3 = Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)

df1 = df[df['Last'].between(q1, q3)]
print (df1)
   A  Last
0  0     1
1  1     2
2  2     3
3  3     5
4  4     8
5  5    10

plt.plot(df1['Last'].values, 'o')
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0,500)
plt.show()
```

---

```
#if want write only Last column
df1[['Last']].to_csv('Training_Data_New.csv', index=False)
#if you want write all columns
df1.to_csv('Training_Data_New.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the Dataframe and it worked. Good to know another way to remove the outlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can `add` you new column variable as a `column` in your `existing_column` and then use pd.to_csv() to save.

After you `get new_column` variable

1. Drop column last from df.

   ```
    df.drop('last',axis=1, inplace=True)
   ```

2.

```
    df['last'] = new_column
```

3. Save your df.

   ```
    df.to_csv('Training_Data_New.csv',index=False)
   ```

Comment: i tried, it didn't work. It gave an Error. ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index